# Rotate rectangle about specific point using PyPlot in Julia

Tags: matplotlib, plot, julia

I am trying to draw and rotate a rectangle about a specific point in Julia using matplotlib for plotting. However, it seems like I have to combine two transformations to make that work, which I don't know how to do.

```
using PyPlot
using PyCall
@pyimport matplotlib.patches as patches
@pyimport matplotlib as mpl

fig = figure(1)
ax = gca()
axis([-4,4,-4,4])

# specify non-rotated rectangle
length = 4
width = 2
rect = patches.Rectangle([1,1],length,width,color="blue",alpha=0.3)
rect_rotated = patches.Rectangle([1,1],length,width,color="red",alpha=0.3)
 # rotate about the following point
point = [3,2]

# try to rotate rectangle using matplotlib's transformations
t1 = mpl.transforms[:Affine2D]()
t1[:rotate_deg_around](point[1],point[2], -30)

# apparently one also has to transform between data coordinate system and display coordinate system
t2 = ax[:transData]
```

What I would like to do now in order to combine the transformations:

```
t3 = t1 + t2
rect_rotated[:set_transform](t3)
ax[:add_patch](rect)
ax[:add_patch](rect_rotated)
```

However, I get the following error

> ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching +(::PyCall.PyObject, ::PyCall.PyObject)

which I believe is because of the PyPlot-Wrapper that doesn't support the "+"-sign to combine the underlying transformations.

Does anyone know how to make this work? Thank you

Comment: Is the + defined in matplotlib? On the transform objects? If so, can you call the __add__ method?

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders Yes, in matplotlib you can combine transformations with the +. However I can't find a corresponding add-function in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python implements operator overloading using methods of the first object, e.g. `t3 = t1 + t2` is equivalent to `t3 = t1.__add__(t2)`.

In Julia, this becomes

`t3 = t1[:__add__](t2)`

Comment: I didn't know about that. But it works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With the remark of @DavidP.Sanders, the working code looks like this:

```
using PyPlot
using PyCall
@pyimport matplotlib.patches as patches
@pyimport matplotlib as mpl

fig = figure(1)
ax =gca()


# specify non-rotated rectangle
length = 4
width = 2
rect = patches.Rectangle([1,1],length,width,color="blue",alpha=0.3)
rect_rotated = patches.Rectangle([1,1],length,width,color="red",alpha=0.3)
 # rotate about the following point
point = [3,2]

# try to rotate rectangle using matplotlib's transformations
t1 = mpl.transforms[:Affine2D]()
t1[:rotate_deg_around](point[1],point[2], -30)

# apparently one also has to transform between data coordinate system and display coordinate system
t2 = ax[:transData]
t3 = t1[:__add__](t2)
rect_rotated[:set_transform](t3)
ax[:add_patch](rect)
ax[:add_patch](rect_rotated)
axis([-1,6,-1,6],"equal")
```

**Result:**
[Rotated rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpz7R.png)

Comment: Glad you got it working. It would be useful to set the aspect ratio to 1 so that the rotated rectangle looks rectangular ;)  I think you need `axis("equal")` at the *end*, not the start. One of the things that has always annoyed me about matplotlib.

Comment: Maybe you could open an issue on the PyPlot.jl repository about the +.